# curl command not executing via shell script in bash

Tags: command-line, scripts, curl, sh

I'm learning shell scripting! For the same I've tried downloading the TCGA genome data using curl on ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS) terminal.

sh. content

```
#!/bin/sh

echo /0c8a6022-b770-4a83-bac3-b1526a16c89a/;

token=$(<gdc-user-token.2018-06-26T14_36_13.548Z.txt)

export ec=18; while [ $ec -ne 0 ]; do curl -C - -H "X-Auth-Token: $token" 'https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/slicing/view/0c8a6022-b770-4a83-bac3-b1526a16c89a?region=chr9:131270948-131270948' > STAD/chr9:131270948-131270948_C440.TCGA-BR-6453-01A-11D-1800-08.3_gdc_realn.bam; export ec=$?;done
```

If I run the sh script, downloaded file is empty, without any error message.

But if the run the command directly then it is working fine.

I will appreciate if anyone let me know the mistake I am doing in the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably not running the script in bash.

`/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash`, the default non-interactive shell in Ubuntu (since version 6.10). `dash` doesn't support the shortcut command `$(<filename)`, so your `token` variable is empty.

To execute the script with bash, change the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash` or explicitly invoke `bash script.sh`.

Generally, if you want/need to use a specific shell, you should explicitly specify it in the shebang line. If you want your script to be portable, you can specify `#!/bin/sh`, but then you have to make sure your script is POSIX-compliant. For example, the POSIX-compliant equivalent of `$(<filename)` would be `$(cat filename)`.

Comment: In particular, `$(< foo)` is a bashism; the POSIX equivalent would be `$(cat foo)` - so `$token` will likely be empty when executed in `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @Salvo Comunque ...and now it works? Which part did you modify?

Comment: @danzel I modified script with  `#!/bin/bash` and `token=$(cat gdc-user-token.2018-06-26T14_36_13.548Z.txt)` thank you ...